# how can i get two classes to interact with eachother

Tags: php

I want to instanciate one class from another class but when i try to call a function of db inside of class foo it fails unless i declasre new db() and call the function inside the same function

```
class foo {
  private $db;
  public function __construct() {
    $db = new db();
// if i call $db->query(); from here it works fine
  }
  public function update(){
  $db->query();
  }
}
class db {
  public function __construct() {
  }
  public function query(){
    echo "returned";
  }
}

$new_class = new foo();
$new_class->update();
```

This code gives me an error saying i have an undefined variable db on line 7 and Call to a member function query() on a non-object.

Comment: I was too slow, `$db` should be `$this->db` for sure

Comment: also by initializing the db in your class foo you are bringing dependency injection to your code.. which is not a good practice.. try to avoid it as much as possible.. use factory patterns..

Comment: @Dinesh your understanding of dependency injection is confused. By instantiating the db connection in the class user1082764 is coupling the two classes together, this is going to lead to much pain down the road. [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) is a pattern used by developers to reduce coupling in their code. With DI, the resources an object requires is _injected_ into the class either at the time it's constructed or via _setter_ methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than `$db`, you should use `$this->db`.

In your code, `$db` is local to the `__construct` function,

```
public function __construct() {
  $db = new db();
  // $db is only available within this function.
}
```

Whereas you want to put it into the member variable, so you need to use `$this` instead,

```
class foo {
  private $db; // To access this, use $this->db in any function in this class

  public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new db();
    // Now you can use $this->db in any other function within foo.
    // (Except for static functions)
  }

  public function update() {
    $this->db->query();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP member variables need to be referenced via `$this`

```
class foo {
  private $db;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->db = new db();
  }

  public function update(){
    $this->db->query();
  }
}
```